# calling [self removeFromSuperview]; from subview doesnot give back control to parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I have created a custom popUp view using UI view.This popupview contains a button and image.

My parent view (with controller) contains a button.On button click, i am adding popup view as subview(see below) -

```
[self.view addSubview:popUp];
```

In my popup view i have handled the click of button as below -

```
- (IBAction)tapHabitatureButton:(id)sender {   
   [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

So on click of popup button,i close my popup.

After my popup get close i can see my parent view. But now my parent view no longer interacts to events.

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[popUP removeFromSuperview ]` instead of  `[self removeFromSuperview]`

Well here i am providing what you need to do 
1. Make instance of your popUP View
Suppose `popUP *view = [popUP alloc]init];`
or create it via  `IBOUTlet` 
Then add it as you are doing 
while removing `popUP` (UIView) from itself take advantage of `delegate` create `protocol` in your `popUP` class that inherits `UIView` and implement it in your `SuperView`

Then use in that function `[popUP removeFromSuperview ]` means remove your popUP instance from superview, You need all that.

Comment: Add explanation is highly recommended .

Comment: i already tried the above approach by creating delegate but somehow delegate method was not getting called.                              can i create a uiview in a button on click and add it in my main view?

Comment: popUP *popviewinstace = [popUP alloc]init];   popviewinstace.delegate = self;

Comment: yes i tried the same way, delegate method was not getting called.            can i create a uiview in a button on click and add it in my main view?

Comment: funkyintelligentguy@yahoo.co.in    thnx in advance

Comment: i sent please check your inbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this you have to change

`[self removeFromSuperview];` to `[popUP removeFromSuperview];` as you want to remove popUP not the self view in which it is being shown.

and

assign the popup as nil like `popUP = nil;` to remove all memory traces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added [self removeFromSuperview]; in my popUp.m. So self here is popUp

Comment: Please note self is the current viewcontroller class... popUp is the popup control you added....

Comment: Sorry for not giving complete information. popUp is my custom UIView class, it has its own xib file, .h and ,m file. I am calling [self removeFromSuperview]; from my popUp.m file. popUp.m file dont have popUp object.

Comment: no that's the problem, when i call  [self removeFromSuperview]; popUp view removes itself, but the control does not go back to parent view

Answer (score 0):

use `[popUp removeFromSuperview];`

instead of `[self removeFromSuperview];`